# How to change springboot context path of weblogic?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I created the project with springboot, weblogic and maven. Also create a simple hello world with jsf. But now i wanna change the url. i tried the change server.servlet.context-path but it doesnt work. what am i doing wrong?

myURL = http://localhost:7001/SpringBootProject/faces/index.xhtml ;

I changed the **application.properties** like following ;

```
spring.application.name= Corp

server.servlet.context-path= /corp

spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsf/

spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



<dependencies>   

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: As I can remember, weblogic only allows deployment of war files. Are you generating the war file instead jar file of your spring boot app? Also, are you using the manually deployment in your weblogic?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify [context-root](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP623) in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`. It will be picked up by the WebLogic and overwrite `server.servlet.context-path`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
                      http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
  <wls:context-root>/corp</wls:context-root>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```